# How can Meteor handle stale connections?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to somehow handle a scenario in which I am getting a corrupted application state:

1. I first open the same app in two browser windows.
2. Turn off wi-fi (or 3g) - connection becomes stale because it was not closed from the remote server.
3. Perform a write operation in the first tab (the second tab will of course not update reactively).
4. Turn on wi-fi.
5. Perform a second write in the first tab (the second tab will now update reactively)
6. So the first tab is now in a corrupted state. The first write will never sync to the server, and if the page reloads, that change will be permanently lost.

Is there a way of handling this stale connection states? Meteor.status().connected remains true throughout this scenario. Is this a Meteor issue that needs to be resolved?

Comment: Are you testing this against a remote server or just localhost? Posting it as an issue on GH could be handy if this is indeed what happens (especially `Meteor.status().connected` should be correct, when I tried it a time ago it worked at expected, or are you testing in a matter of some seconds?).

Comment: I'm testing with a remote server, disabling wi-fi does not affect a localhost connection :). I have just posted this on github as well https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/339

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been tagged as a confirmed bug on Meteor's github page

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/339

Answer (score 0):

edit:

forget it, unfortunately my assumptions didnt work out :(

http://jqm.meteor.com does commit the changes when reconnecting,

but Meteor.status() indeed doesnt work on that page.

on meteor.com it does,
which is weird, because afaik the whole meteor cloud should run on 0.4.0, not only the hosted apps?

have fun

manarius